# Proper use of SELECT(MAX) when the number looks like 23-999

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am having trouble with the use of `SELECT(MAX)` to get the next number. When the number is 23-999 I will get 23-1000. Then when the next number is needed like 23-1001, I get 23-1000.

Here is my SQL statement

```
string SQL = @"SELECT MAX (Purchase_Order_Number)
               FROM dbo.Purchase_Order
               WHERE Purchase_Order_Number LIKE '__-%';";

using (DataAccessClass.sql_Connection)
using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, DataAccessClass.sql_Connection))
{
    DataTable Next_PO = CreateTablesClass.Create_Table(SQL, "Next_PO");
    string last_Purchase_Order_Number = Next_PO.Rows[0][0].ToString();
    int po = last_Purchase_Order_Number.IndexOf('-');
    po_number = Convert.ToInt32(last_Purchase_Order_Number.Substring(po + 1));
}
```

If I change my SQL statement to this it works as expected. But then when we get to 23-9999, what then?

```
string SQL = @"SELECT MAX (Purchase_Order_Number)
               FROM dbo.Purchase_Order
               WHERE Purchase_Order_Number LIKE '__-____%';";
```

Comment: A couple of questions:  Are all of your purchase order numbers in the form of a two-digit numerical prefix followed by a dash and then a number?  And should the two-digit prefix count in the ordering?  For example should "23-1" be considered larger than "22-9999"?

Comment: "23-999" is not a number, it's a string of characters; if 23 and 999 have separate meaning they should be in two integer columns = data normalised, problem solved.

Comment: Mark, yes that is correct

Comment: Stu, thanks for the 'data normalized' thought.  these numbers are Purchase Order numbers.  the first 2 digits represent the year and after the hyphen is the actual PO number.  this number could be anything from 1 - 1,000,000,000

Comment: You can't do it like this. `MAX` on text data always uses text sorting which means `23-2` is always larger than `23-999` or `23-1001`. Besides, `MAX+1` guarantees duplicates if a row is deleted. SQL Server has SEQUENCE objects that solve such problems. Instead of trying to update a text field, use two different numeric fields for the year and sequence number and use a calculated column to create the invoice string

Comment: `whom ever down voted this question` I didn't but there are a lot of similar questions. The real solution is to normalize the data and use a SEQUENCE object or table to calculate the PO field.

Comment: @DaveHampel So yes you have two atomic integer values each with a specific meaning munged into a single text column - that's one of the most common sources of issues there is; Why do you even need the prefix? You must have a column somewhere that records a date/time so a computed column could easily provide a year prefix with the actual PO number.

Comment: @Stu thanks for the straight up answer. That is extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`23-999` is a string, not a number, so the `MAX` value is the "largest" value in alphabetical order. Since `9` is after `1` alphabetically, `23-999` is "larger" than `23-1000`, so MAX(PO) will always give you `23-999`, and your logic to compute the next number will give you `23-1000`.

One option is to take the max number after the dash, but it's not clear when the PO number rolls to `24-XXX` - I presume at the end of the year, which could be incorporates into your logic also.

You can't just remove the dash and treat it as a number, since `24-100` will be less than `23-1000` if you just remove the dash.

Answer (score 0):

The number that I am working with is a Work Order Number, Purchase Order Number or a Repair Order Number.  All of which have the same basic meaning.  The first 2 digits are the year they were created.  The digits after the hyphen is the sequential numbering of the Work, Purchase or Repair Order.

I have changed my SQL data column to a standard string that hold the sequential numbering for the Work, Purchase and Repair Order.  I have my reasons to use a string rather than int.

When I put together my SQL statement and select the year from the Date column and the number from the Work, Purchase or Repair order and hook them together using the following line in my SQL Statement.

```
SELECT RIGHT(YEAR(Work_Order_Date), 2) + '-' + Work_Order_Number AS Work_Order_Number
FROM dbo.Work_Order;
```

Thanks to `Stu` for the perfect and straight up answer.

My code to get the next Work, Purchase or Repair order number is as follows

```
private int Get_Next_PO_Number()
{
    int po_number = 0;
    string SQL = @"SELECT Work_Order_Number
                     FROM dbo.Work_Order
                 ORDER BY Purchase_Order_ID DESC;";
    using (DataAccessClass.sql_Connection)
    using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, 
                    DataAccessClass.sql_Connection))
    {
        DataTable Next_PO = CreateTablesClass.Create_Table(SQL, "Next_PO");
        po_number = Convert.ToInt32(Next_PO.Rows[0][0].ToString());
    }
    return po_number++;
}
```

We are no longer using `SELECT MAX()` at all

Answer (score -1):

As others have stated there is a problem with normalization that will complicate the query.

Since the [Purchase_Order_Number] column is non-atomic (containing year and Purchase Order #), it requires going into every value of every row to extract parts. That requires a table scan and can't use an index. The resulting workaround is a mountain of code and/or frustration.

While it requires more code and horrible performance, there is a technical answer.

To humor you I'll write a solution- and no this isn't a serious answer. The purpose is to illustrate how non-atomic data requires extraction and complicates querying.

```
--Example of non-atomic table design and "workaround" query
CREATE TABLE #Purchase_Order (Purchase_Order_Number varchar(50));
INSERT INTO #Purchase_Order VALUES ('23-999'), ('23-1000'), ('23-1001');

WITH CTE_table_scan AS (
SELECT Purchase_Order_Number
  FROM #Purchase_Order
 WHERE Purchase_Order_Number LIKE '23-%'
)
,CTE_year_ordernum AS (
--extracting parts, then casting parts of the string to int
SELECT [yearval] = CAST(LEFT(Purchase_Order_Number, 2) as int)
      ,[ordernum] = CAST(STUFF(Purchase_Order_Number, 1, 3, '') --eliminate the 1st 3 characters with STUFF()
                         as int)
  FROM CTE_table_scan
)
,CTE_maxyear AS (
--acquiring the max year
SELECT [maxYear] = MAX(yearval)
  FROM CTE_year_ordernum
)
,CTE_maxordernum AS (
SELECT (SELECT maxYear
          FROM CTE_maxyear) AS [maxYear]
       --acquiring the max ordernum for the max year
      ,MAX(ordernum) AS [maxOrderNum]
  FROM CTE_year_ordernum 
)

SELECT --concatenate ints back to strings to match your label
       CONCAT(CAST(maxYear as varchar(2))
             ,'-'
             ,CAST(maxOrderNum as varchar(50))) AS [Max_Purchase_Order_Number]
  FROM CTE_maxordernum
```

Produces output:

```
Max_Purchase_Order_Number
--------------------------
23-1001
```

Instead of that...
Here is an atomic table example (and I would not record the 2 digits of the year by itself so this is just for illustration):

```
--Example of atomic table design
CREATE TABLE #Purchase_Order2 (YearVal int, Purchase_Order_Number int);
INSERT INTO #Purchase_Order2 VALUES (23, 999), (23, 1000), (23, 1001);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_temp_PurchaseOrder2 
        ON #Purchase_Order2 (YearVal DESC, Purchase_Order_Number DESC);

SELECT CONCAT(YearVal
             ,'-'
             ,MAX(Purchase_Order_Number)) AS [Max_Purchase_Order_Number]
  FROM #Purchase_Order2
 WHERE YearVal = 23
GROUP BY YearVal
```

And produces output:

```
Max_Purchase_Order_Number
-------------------------
23-1001
```

Not only is the code substantially shorter but it uses an index seek, which is faster and more efficient than the other example's table scan.